# Adding sound to a demonstration so I can video my lectures

Tags: sound, slideshows

During my lectures I often stop PowerPoint and do a demonstration using a Mathematica `DynamicModule` these have sliders and buttons as needed. I am now in lockdown due to Covid19 and I am preparing lectures using the feature of voice over PowerPoint for recording my presentation. What is the best way to create an mp4 file that has my voice explaining what I am doing as I operate my Mathematica demonstration?  I only have the windows environment which includes a laptop camera and a microphone. I am happy to tell the viewer to switch off the PowerPoint and to watch another presentation before coming back.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try googling "screen recording software" -- almost any of these will allow you to record your screen and your voice, then save to common video formats like mp4.

Comment: @bills Thanks. I will investigate, pity I can't do it all in Mathematica.